# Hex color function for IOS in Kotlin-Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

This is for whoever needs it, it is a function that converts a hex string and returns a UIColor.
This is for whoever needs it, it is a function that converts a hex string and returns a UIColor.

```
import kotlinx.cinterop.UIntVar
import kotlinx.cinterop.memScoped
import kotlinx.cinterop.ptr
import platform.CoreGraphics.CGFloat
import platform.Foundation.NSScanner
import platform.Foundation.scanHexInt
import platform.UIKit.UIColor
import kotlinx.cinterop.alloc
import kotlinx.cinterop.value

fun hexToUIColor(hexStr: String): UIColor {
    var cString: String = hexStr.toUpperCase()

    if (cString.startsWith("#")) {
        cString = cString.removePrefix("#")
    }

    if (cString.length != 8) {
        return UIColor.grayColor
    }

    var a: UInt
    var r: UInt
    var g: UInt
    var b: UInt

    memScoped {
        val scanner = NSScanner(cString)
        var pointed : UIntVar = alloc<UIntVar>()
        scanner.scanHexInt(pointed.ptr)
        val alpha: CGFloat = 1.0
        val pointedValue: UInt = pointed.value

        a = ((pointedValue and 4278190080u) shl 24) / 255u
        r = ((pointedValue and 16711680u) shl 16) / 255u
        g = ((pointedValue and 65280u) shl 8) / 255u
        b = ((pointedValue and 255u) shl 0) / 255u

        return UIColor(red = r.toDouble(), green = g.toDouble(), blue = b.toDouble(), alpha = a.toDouble())
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't dividing by 255u "kill" the values (reduce it to 0 unless it's 255)? "and-ing" could be with 255 after the shift. And the shift should be to the right?